# conversation language translation

Tags: translation, language

If two characters have a conversation one in a foreign tongue the other in english should there ba an asterisk and a translation of foreign language some where else or from the english speaking characters dialogue could the other be inferred

Comment: Im not asking how to show im asking if the average reader can infer from the english speakers response to the foreign language

Comment: My answer to that question also details how much of the non-English language you can use before you need to translate, and where to put that translation.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Could the two perhaps be merged?

Comment: @PraveshParekh Got me; ask a mod. I'm not even sure what that does with a question like this with no answers.